# Explorer из браузера

Tags: php, explorer

Доброго времени суток. У меня возникла проблема странного характера: надо открыть окно виндового explorer'а с заданным адресом из браузера.

Откуда растут "ноги" этой задачи? Есть табличка со списком файлов, получаемая через ftp-доступ. А клиент не знает про filemanager'ы и ему влом качать несколько файлов по одному, поэтому нужна кнопка "скачать папку". Решение "скачать папку и файлы - архивировать - отдать архив" - это на самый крайний случай, проще открыть explorer со строкой ftp://доступы .

Если это невозможно, есть вариант открыть ftp://доступы во вкладке браузера и написать инструкцию, как открыть через explorer, но это тоже не комильфо. Есть ли лучшие варианты?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного не понял, нужно открыть ie на сервере или клиенте (на машине у пользователя сайта) ? Если первое то воспользуйтесь функциями потипу этой http://php.su/functions/?system , если 2 то это не возможно сделать просто так по вполне понятным причинам безопастности, это возможно только если найдете уязвимость в браузере пользователя и будете ее использоваться для открытия ie :)

Comment: Надо на машине пользователя открыть explorer (не IE).

Comment: Не получиться у вас это, отписал уже выше почему

Comment: Хм... перечитал вопрос, explorer.exe и iexplore.exe разные вещи, не внимателен был...

Конечно есть идея указать ссылку на *.bat файл, клиент его скачает, и запустит, а дальше дело техники.

explorer.exe C:\FileDirectory\Folder

Comment: Ясно. А есть ли способ открыть адрес вида `ftp://логин:пароль@сервер:порт/папка1/папка11`, чтобы не пришлось вводить логин и пароль для доступа к `/папка1/папка11`?

Comment: Видимо можно, пробуйте...теория это теория...
Я сейчас попробывал, подключлся

explorer.exe ftp://user:password@ftp.server.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Вот что сказал гугл

> http://www.oszone.net/14822/IE9_CMD

Или иными словами

Win + R -> **iexplore.exe** *sitename.com*

Comment: Гут. А как сделать Win + R -> **iexplore.exe** *sitename.com* по нажатию кнопки в браузере?